# Windows compiler for C# project

Tags: windows, gratis, c#, compiler

Which software/environment could I use to run this project? It's a pretty old one, from 2007 I think. It contains .cs and .resx files.

Requirements:

- Free
- As easy as possible to just compile the project

Answer (score 5):

[Visual Studio 2015](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/visual-studio-community-vs.aspx) is what you need. Microsoft provides a free community version.

[image: Visual Studio 2015]

Comment: Probably any version released after 2007, but 2015 would probably be the best bet and easiest to obtain.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Visual Studio you could give the [Mono](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mono_(software)) Project & the [monodevelop](http://www.monodevelop.com) IDR a try.

### Screenshots

CRM Services App project on Windows 10
[image]
The following is an example of an Android targeted sample screenshot on Windows 10.
[image]
An iOS app screenshot from the web site
[image]